# Writing a vectorised function in R

Tags: r, function, vectorization

I have written the following function:

```
asteriks = function(pvalue){
  if(pvalue > 0.05){
    output = "NS"
  }else if (pvalue <=0.05 & pvalue >0.01){
    output = "*"
  }else if (pvalue <=0.01 & pvalue >0.001){
    output = "**"
  }else if (pvalue <=0.001 & pvalue >0.0001){
    output = "***"
  }else if (pvalue <=0.0001){
    output = "****"
  }
  return(output)
}
```

It works fine when I provide an argument of length 1, but I would like the function to take a vector of length >1 as an input and return a vector of the same length.

example of what I would like to do:

```
vector_pvals = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.001, 0.0001)
asteriks(vector_pvals)
```

The output should be a character vector like this:

```
[1] "NS" "*" "***" "****"
```

I can achieved this by using the function in a `for`-loop of course, but I actually want to use it within a `dplyr` pipe, so it would be nice to be able to just feed it a whole vector. Is the answer to use a `for`-loop within the function to work one each element one at a time, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 7):

Here you don't need to write your own function. `cut` does exactly what you're looking for (this is by far the simplest method)

```
pvalues <- seq(0, 0.1, by = 0.0001)
cut(pvalues,
    breaks = c(-Inf, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, Inf), 
    include.lowest = TRUE, 
    right = FALSE, 
    labels = c('****', '***', '**', '*', 'NS'))
```

If you want to make this an exercise in "vectorizing" you can convert your function in several ways, both using `ifelse` as suggested by another answer, creating an index matching each group or using multiple indexes. `ifelse` is the simplest of the methods.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ifelse` instead of `if`. It is designed to be vectorized.  Your function could be written as

```
asteriks = function(pvalue){
  ifelse(pvalue > 0.05, "NS",
  ifelse(pvalue > 0.01, "*",
  ifelse(pvalue > 0.001, "**",
  ifelse(pvalue >0.0001, "***", "****"))))
}
```

For other functions with more complicated computations where this isn't possible, you can use the `Vectorize()` function to convert a function to vectorized form (by running a loop internally).  For example,

```
asteriksV <- Vectorize(asteriks)
```

Now `asteriksV` would work even with your original definition of `asteriks`.

Comment: Thank you, both of these solutions worked perfectly and the `vectorize()` option is great as a general solution, too. I guess the series of nested `ifelse` statements might get confusing if there are many more of them, in which case the solution using `cut` suggested above could be easier.

Answer (score 3):

With breaks at powers of 10 `strrep`:

```
asteriks <- function(pvalue) {
  ifelse(pvalue > 0.05, "NS", strrep("*", pmin(-log10(pvalue), 4)))
}

asteriks(c(0.1, 0.05, 0.001, 0.0001))
#> [1] "NS"   "*"    "***"  "****"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to add up on the exercise of different methods.

```
asteriks <- function(p) {
  v <- c("*" = 0.05, "**" = 0.01, "***" = 0.001, "****" = 0.0001)
  ifelse(p > max(v), "NS", names(v[v <= p][1]))
}

vector_pvals = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.001, 0.0001)

unlist(lapply(vector_pvals, asteriks))

[1] "NS"   "*"    "***"  "****"
```